# Trouble with Parsing JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, json

I generated the following json in my views.py

```
page_data= {'injured_json': '[{"pk": 24, "model": "appvisual.injured_count", "fields": {"Y_2010": 75445, "Y_2008": 70251, "Y_2009": 70504, "Y_2004": 57283, "Y_2005": 62006, "Y_2006": 64342, "Y_2007": 71099, "State_UT": "Tamil Nadu", "Y_2003": 55242, "Y_2011": 74245}}]'}
```

I passed this json to my javascript. My question is how can  i manipulate over this json in my javascript.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
function test() {
    var dataRows = {{page_data}};
    console.log(dataRows.injured_json[0].pk); };
```

Edit : My Full json object to the javascript

```
{'injured_json': '[{"pk": 24, "model": "appvisual.injured_count", "fields": {"Y_2010": 75445, "Y_2008": 70251, "Y_2009": 70504, "Y_2004": 57283, "Y_2005": 62006, "Y_2006": 64342, "Y_2007": 71099, "State_UT": "Tamil Nadu", "Y_2003": 55242, "Y_2011": 74245}}]', 'total_json': '[{"pk": 23, "model": "appvisual.total_accident", "fields": {"Y_2010": 64996, "Y_2008": 60409, "Y_2009": 60794, "Y_2004": 52508, "Y_2005": 53866, "Y_2006": 55145, "Y_2007": 59140, "State_UT": "Tamil Nadu", "Y_2003": 51025, "Y_2011": 65873}}]', 'killed_json': '[{"pk": 24, "model": "appvisual.killed_count", "fields": {"Y_2010": 75445, "Y_2008": 70251, "Y_2009": 70504, "Y_2004": 57283, "Y_2005": 62006, "Y_2006": 64342, "Y_2007": 71099, "State_UT": "Tamil Nadu", "Y_2003": 55242, "Y_2011": 74245}}, {"pk": 60, "model": "appvisual.killed_count", "fields": {"Y_2010": 15409, "Y_2008": 12784, "Y_2009": 13746, "Y_2004": 9507, "Y_2005": 9758, "Y_2006": 11009, "Y_2007": 12036, "State_UT": "Tamil Nadu", "Y_2003": 9275, "Y_2011": 15422}}]'}
```

**NOTE:**

I found that the json data i sent is not a valid json. i rectified it. but now the prolem is, i am sending the json data in dictionary. while receiving the json data in javascrpit,the format becomes **(** *json data* **)**. because of extra added " **(**" and "**)**" , i could not parse the json in javascript. how can i eliminate "**(**" and "**)**" to parse the json data in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

See [JSON.parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

```
var page_data= {'injured_json': '[{"pk": 24, "model": "appvisual.injured_count"}]'},
    dataRows = JSON.parse(page_data.injured_json);

console.log(dataRows[0].pk);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But console.log throws an error stating "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"

Comment: @Chuvi With this script ?

Comment: yup with this script only

Comment: it doesn't support nested Json, Include fields and then try.. its not working yar

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why everyone is pointing to `JSON.parse`. The issue here is that you're attempting to access an array, but it's actually a string. Simply remove the quotes from around the array.

Actually... You don't need an array at all. I think you are looking for something more like this:

```
{
    "injured_json": {
        "pk": 24,
        "model": "appvisual.injured_count",
        "fields": {
            "Y_2010": 75445,
            "Y_2008": 70251,
            "Y_2009": 70504,
            "Y_2004": 57283,
            "Y_2005": 62006,
            "Y_2006": 64342,
            "Y_2007": 71099,
            "State_UT": "Tamil Nadu",
            "Y_2003": 55242,
            "Y_2011": 74245
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was just with the json formatting.

```
console.log(page_data.injured_json.pk); // logs 24
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON`:

```
function test() {
    var data = "{{page_data}}";
    var dataRows = JSON.parse(data.injured_json);
    console.log(dataRows[0].pk); };
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But console.log throws an error stating "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"

Comment: @positlabs I suppose he is sending the "Json object" from django so he must use double braces to read the variable in javascript

Comment: @Chuvi If you are sending the "Json object" from django how are you sending it? are you using json.dumps with the correct mimetype?

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres: you are correct im sending json object to script. see my edits for my full json object sent to script. by the way im She.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres: im using simplejson.dumps, mimetype is application/json

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44543/discussion-between-chuvi-and-victor-castillo-torres)

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres: Yeah it worked :). Actually there was a problem with my Json data. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934510/syntax-error-while-parsing-json-data-in-javascript