# Syntax error while parsing Json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, json

I am returning this in my views.py through a dictionary

```
{"injured_json": [{"pk": 24, "model": "appvisual.injured_count", "fields": {"Y_2010": 75445, "Y_2008": 70251, "Y_2009": 70504, "Y_2004": 57283, "Y_2005": 62006, "Y_2006": 64342, "Y_2007": 71099, "State_UT": "Tamil Nadu", "Y_2003": 55242, "Y_2011": 74245}}], "total_json": [{"pk": 23, "model": "appvisual.total_accident", "fields": {"Y_2010": 64996, "Y_2008": 60409, "Y_2009": 60794, "Y_2004": 52508, "Y_2005": 53866, "Y_2006": 55145, "Y_2007": 59140, "State_UT": "Tamil Nadu", "Y_2003": 51025, "Y_2011": 65873}}], "killed_json": [{"pk": 24, "model": "appvisual.killed_count", "fields": {"Y_2010": 75445, "Y_2008": 70251, "Y_2009": 70504, "Y_2004": 57283, "Y_2005": 62006, "Y_2006": 64342, "Y_2007": 71099, "State_UT": "Tamil Nadu", "Y_2003": 55242, "Y_2011": 74245}}, {"pk": 60, "model": "appvisual.killed_count", "fields": {"Y_2010": 15409, "Y_2008": 12784, "Y_2009": 13746, "Y_2004": 9507, "Y_2005": 9758, "Y_2006": 11009, "Y_2007": 12036, "State_UT": "Tamil Nadu", "Y_2003": 9275, "Y_2011": 15422}}]}
```

while retrieving the about json in javascript, the json data gets enclosed with ( and ) as follows :

```
({injured_json:[{pk:24, model:"appvisual.injured_count", fields:{Y_2010:75445, Y_2008:70251, Y_2009:70504, Y_2004:57283, Y_2005:62006, Y_2006:64342, Y_2007:71099, State_UT:"Tamil Nadu", Y_2003:55242, Y_2011:74245}}], total_json:[{pk:23, model:"appvisual.total_accident", fields:{Y_2010:64996, Y_2008:60409, Y_2009:60794, Y_2004:52508, Y_2005:53866, Y_2006:55145, Y_2007:59140, State_UT:"Tamil Nadu", Y_2003:51025, Y_2011:65873}}], killed_json:[{pk:24, model:"appvisual.killed_count", fields:{Y_2010:75445, Y_2008:70251, Y_2009:70504, Y_2004:57283, Y_2005:62006, Y_2006:64342, Y_2007:71099, State_UT:"Tamil Nadu", Y_2003:55242, Y_2011:74245}}, {pk:60, model:"appvisual.killed_count", fields:{Y_2010:15409, Y_2008:12784, Y_2009:13746, Y_2004:9507, Y_2005:9758, Y_2006:11009, Y_2007:12036, State_UT:"Tamil Nadu", Y_2003:9275, Y_2011:15422}}]})
```

Because of additionally added "**(**" and "**)**" i could not parse the json dta in javascript. How can i eliminate this syntax error.

My Views.py

```
def get_details(request):
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace();
    total_details = total_accident.objects.filter(State_UT='Tamil Nadu')
    total_details = serializers.serialize('python', total_details)
    killed_details = Killed_Count.objects.filter(State_UT='Tamil Nadu')
    killed_details = serializers.serialize('python', killed_details)
    injured_details = Injured_Count.objects.filter(State_UT='Tamil Nadu')
    injured_details = serializers.serialize('python', injured_details)
    page_data = {
    "total_json" : total_details,
    "killed_json" : killed_details,
    "injured_json" : injured_details,
    }
    page_data= simplejson.dumps(page_data)
    print page_data
    return render_to_response('dvslzer.html', {'page_data':page_data})
```

My Script:

```
function test() {

    var dataRows = {{page_data}};
    console.log(dataRows.toSource()); 
    var data=JSON.parse(dataRows.total_accident); // throws syntax error
    console.log(data[0].pk);
};
```

Is there any solution to get rid of this syntax error??

Comment: Don't add the parentheses. (Why are they added in the first place?)

Comment: @nnnnnn: If i remove "{{" and "}}" then it throws reference error

Comment: Parentheses are the round brackets `()`, which you say get added along the way for some reason. In any case, the JSON that you show at the beginning of your question doesn't have a property called `total_accident`, so wouldn't `dataRows.total_accident` be undefined? Which in turn would mean that `JSON.parse(dataRows.total_accident)` _should_ give you an error...

Comment: @nnnnnn: nope everything is well defined. And i dint add that parantheses.. it gets added wen i print them on the console.log

Comment: Note: Its not just the parentheses, valid JSON strings **require** the key names to be in quotes as well, i.e. like in the original data you are returning

Comment: _"everything is well defined."_ - No it's not. You start your question by showing a JSON string that definitely does not include a `total_accident` property, yet in your JS code you try to use a property of that name.

Comment: @nnnnnn : i agree. instead of total_json i used total accident..

Comment: Ah. Then you can just say `var data = dataRows.total_json;`. You don't need `JSON.parse()` because by that stage you're not dealing with JSON, you have an actual JS object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piecing together what we managed to establish in comments above, this line:

```
var data=JSON.parse(dataRows.total_accident);
```

...should actually be:

```
var data = dataRows.total_json;
```

Because firstly there is no property in the object called `total_accident`, and secondly it doesn't make sense to try to use `JSON.parse()` because you're not actually dealing with JSON at that point.

(The JS isn't really dealing with JSON at all, because the server-side `{{page_data}}` outputs the JSON directly into the page source, so by the time the browser sees it it just appears as an object literal in your JS code. If it was JSON you'd need to use `JSON.parse()` on `dataRows` before you could start accessing properties with dot notation.)

Answer (score 0):

You could process the data first and then parse it as JSON.

```
var data;

// removes first and last characters from data
data = data.substring(1, data.length - 1);

// convert data to JSON
data = JSON.parse(data);
```